# How do I verify the correct input payload format for the Business Rules on Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

I want to make sure that the payload I pass to the ruleset request for the Business Rules service on Bluemix is correctly formed. How do I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following GET request on the URL to generate a JSON payload:
https://brsv2-12345678.ng.bluemix.net/DecisionService/rest/MyRuleApp/2.0/myrules/1.0/json

For an XML payload, I used the following:
I used the following GET request on the URL to generate a XML payload:
https://brsv2-12345678.ng.bluemix.net/DecisionService/rest/MyRuleApp/2.0/myrules/1.0/xml

I was able to do the same from the Bluemix console.
I used the Decision Services tab of the Business Rules service instance, and clicked on the arrow beside the ruleset with the tooltip "Test your service". This displayed a "Decision Request". I chose the JSON format and the corresponding sample payload data was generated under "Decision Request". I could have also chosen the XML format.

I pasted the input data payload I was working with and clicked on "Run Test" to ensure my input data was also correctly formed. If it was incorrectly formed, I got an "Unable to run test" error, whose details showed what was incorrect.